# What distinguishes geometry from algebra and topology as a field of study--is all geometry metric geometry?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, math-history

I've always been fascinated and somewhat confused by why some concepts are deemed geometric, topological, or algebraic in nature. Would it be fair to say that some notion of distance is requisite for a subject area to be called geometry? Is there any subfield of geometry that does not directly borrow from the study of metric spaces?

Comment: The study of topology is independent of metric spaces, and there are interesting topological spaces which are non-metrizable. Moreover, Algebraic Geometry is a vast subject where geometrical objects are studied from a non-metric perspective: one particular notion, which has no equivalent in point-set geometry, is that of _non-reducedness_. I hope this can be an interesting starting point!

Comment: Start with projective geometry. The key notion is incidence.